# Clickable background image in email - Outlook issue

Tags: email, html-email

I'm using the bulletproof method to overlay some text ontop of an image so it looks like this:

[image: cool]

My code is as follows (not sure why image doesn't render in snippet, pasting html code in browser it will show):

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="ppp-ideabooks__image" background="http://www.autointell.com/News-2014/August-2014/toyota-ft-1-sports-concept.jpg" bgcolor="#fff" style="width: 340px; height: 198px; vertical-align: bottom; padding: 0;">
           <!--[if gte mso 9]>
           <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:340px;height:198px;">
              <v:fill type="tile" src="http://www.autointell.com/News-2014/August-2014/toyota-ft-1-sports-concept.jpg" color="#fff" />
              <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                 <![endif]--> <a class="ppp-ideabooks__link" href="#" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 90%;"></a>
                 <p class="ppp-ideabooks__text" style="display: inline-block; margin: 0; padding: 5px 12px; background-color: #4dbc15; color: #000; letter-spacing: 1px; font-size: 15px; font-family: HelveticaNeueMedium,HelveticaNeue-Medium,'Helvetica Neue Medium',HelveticaNeue,'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">
                    "COOL CARS"
                 </p>
                 <!--[if gte mso 9]>
              </v:textbox>
           </v:rect>
           <![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This works fine, but on Outlook it looks like this:

[image: outlook]

Does anyone know how to fix this issue for Outlook? Note that I'm trying to make the image clickable which is why I have the `<a>` tag inside as well...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed a few things around in your code and the result is at the bottom of this answer.

Basically you had the type as tile (`<v:fill type="tile"`). This will tile the image when the content inside the block is larger. Unless you have a background that is meant to be tiled, you suggest sticking to `<v:fill type="frame"`.

I also added a table in the comments as paragraphs can use unwanted spaces (above and below the text) if CSS is not applied properly. First row is to space it out, second row has the text as a link.

**Edit - Added the following:**

- `href` to VML
- conditional space for Outlooks
- a span tag for green bar
- padding to href to make the whole block clickable

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="top" class="ppp-ideabooks__image" background="http://www.autointell.com/News-2014/August-2014/toyota-ft-1-sports-concept.jpg" bgcolor="#fff" style="width: 340px; height: 198px; padding: 0;vertical-align: top;">
           <!--[if gte mso 9]>
           <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" href="http://www.google.com" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:340px;height:198px;">
              <v:fill type="frame" src="http://www.autointell.com/News-2014/August-2014/toyota-ft-1-sports-concept.jpg" color="#fff" />
              <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                 <![endif]--> 
            
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height:171px;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <![endif]-->
                    <tr>
                        <td class="ppp-ideabooks__text" style=""><a class="ppp-ideabooks__link" href="#" style="display: inline-block;box-sizing: border-box; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none;padding: 170px 204px 0px 0px;">
                         
                            <span style="display: inline-block; margin: 0; padding: 5px 12px; background-color: #4dbc15; color: #000; letter-spacing: 1px; font-size: 15px; font-family: HelveticaNeueMedium,HelveticaNeue-Medium,'Helvetica Neue Medium',HelveticaNeue,'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">"COOL CARS"</span></a>
                         </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
                 <!--[if gte mso 9]>
              </v:textbox>
           </v:rect>
           <![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How the above code renders in Litmus (Feb/2019)

[image]

Hope this is the answer you were after.

Comment: Thanks much for the help. Just wondering, have you tested to see if the anchor tag covers the whole image? Because I want to entire `<td>` to be clickable.

Comment: @MarksCode, I have updated the code above with `hrefs` in the right place. You will need to change paddings in mobile versions with media queries.

Comment: Thankyou. Wouldn't just putting an `<a>` around the inside `<table>` be a better solution though?

Comment: @MarksCode in web yes. But in emails Outlooks have a weird way of rendering HTML. If you want to see how it looks, try removing the conditional block for the extra row and see how it renders in Outlook and the extra padding code. It will show what we email coders go thru everyday trying to cater for every device :-)

Comment: Seems to be rendering fine on outlooks in litmus with putting `<a>` around table for me.

Comment: It renders fine, yes **but** the a tag will not be clickable. For clicks in Outlook I have placed the href on the VML. For all other email clients the a tag should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook clients are ignoring quite a few style properties along with not rendering tables the way you would expect at times. 
By the looks of your screenshot it seems as if the specified height of the table is not honoured in Outlook.

I suggest you try setting the width and height to the table and td properties instead.

```
<table width="340" height="198" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td background="http://www.autointell.com/News-2014/August-2014/toyota-ft-1-sports-concept.jpg" width="340" height="198" style="width: 340px; height: 198px; vertical-align: bottom; padding: 0;">
       <!--[if gte mso 9]>
       <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:340px;height:198px;">
          <v:fill type="tile" src="http://www.autointell.com/News-2014/August-2014/toyota-ft-1-sports-concept.jpg" color="#fff" />
          <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
             <![endif]--> <a href="#" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 90%;"></a>
             <p class="ppp-ideabooks__text" style="display: inline-block; margin: 0; padding: 5px 12px; background-color: #4dbc15; color: #000; letter-spacing: 1px; font-size: 15px; font-family: HelveticaNeueMedium,HelveticaNeue-Medium,'Helvetica Neue Medium',HelveticaNeue,'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">
                "COOL CARS"
             </p>
             <!--[if gte mso 9]>
          </v:textbox>
       </v:rect>
       <![endif]-->
    </td>
</tr>
```

I´m guessing the image in your snippet does not show since it is served over http.
If the snippet contains the entire html content of the message, consider adding html, header and body tags to it to increase deliverability.

The example below is untested as I do not have access to an Outlook client at the moment.